# sd card not showing as mmcblk but as sdX

Tags: sd-card

I have a question, I am using manjaro Linux and installed yay and sdtool , to remove the temp write protect from my SD card , but the SD card isnt shown as mmcblk like that but it's showing sda or sdb , what is the cause !? Or is there any other way to remove the write protect from CSD of the micro sd card

Comment: The mmcblkN device node would indicate that the CPU is interacting with an MMC/SD controller. This is typical for Linux on SoCs that have an embedded MMC/SD controller. A PC is more likely to have an off-board module incorporating the SD card socket and a USB adapter chip; the USB interface exposes an sdX device node for the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

> but the SD card isnt shown as mmcblk like that but it's showing sda or sdb , what is the cause !?

The cause is that your computer has a USB-connected card reader. (Internal USB, that is.) You only get `mmcblk` devices from PCI-connected (SDHCI) card readers, which allow the OS to talk directly to the card (i.e. send actual MMC commands), whereas USB readers translate everything into SCSI (and as a result, instead of talking to the card, the OS can only talk to the reader). It's the same situation as with SATA or NVMe disks connected directly vs connected via USB.

Many laptop manufacturers use USB-based readers as those are probably easier to integrate (and I'm guessing also cheaper).